# Laravel 5.2 LengthAwarePaginator does not show any result on navigating to next page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using a LengthAwarePaginator which paginates the results obtained from Twitter api. The first page works just fine but as i navigate to the any other page through the paginated links, it does not give any result.

Routes:

```
Route::any('/search', ['uses' => 'TweetController@getSearch', 'as' => 'search']);
```

TweetController:

```
public function getSearch(Request $request)
{
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $perPage = 6;

    $tweetArray = Twitter::getUserTimeline(['screen_name' => $request['search'], 'count' => $request['count']]);

    $tweetPerPage = array_slice($tweetArray, (($currentPage-1) * $perPage), $perPage, true);

    $tweets = new LengthAwarePaginator($tweetPerPage, count($tweetArray), $perPage, $currentPage, ['path' => $request->url()]);

    return view('tweets', ['tweets' => $tweets]);
}
```

tweet.blade.php:

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search using Twitter Handle" name="search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="number">How many?</span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type"submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="10">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu > li').click(function() {
        var cnt = $(this).children().html();
        $('input[type="hidden"]').val(cnt);
        $('.number').html(cnt);
    });
});
</script>
<hr />      
@foreach($tweets as $tweet)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#">
                      <img class="media-object" src="{{ $tweet->user->profile_image_url }}">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $tweet->user->name }}</h4>
                    {{ $tweet->text }}
                  </div>
                  <small class="pull-right">{{ Twitter::ago($tweet->created_at) }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            {!! $tweets->render() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```